# how to grant site permission directly to a specific user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

[image: Here in this image trying to assign site permission to a specific user without adding that user in any user group but submit/share button is not visible.Then how to assign site permission this user?]

I am trying to assign site permission to a specific user without adding that user in any user group but submit/share button is not visible.Then how to assign site permission this user?

Comment: actually,by default you can assign permission to the users without adding in any group. there might be other issue that you are having. are you facing this issue only for particular site collection or can you try by creating another site collection??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your account has this permission:
[image]

If yes, it seems that the Shared button has been hidden or it’s caused by browser compatibility issue. Please check for html and CSS code via F12. And change other browsers.